# Solving Third order Differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I just had This Third order differential equation but i don't got any idea how to solve it cause mathematica doesn't get me a straight answer does anyone got any idea? I just know from the paper i'm redriving it that it has modified bessel functions 1st and 2nd as answer I would be glad if you could help me.

```
DSolve[{D[f[u], {u, 3}]/f[u] - (3/2)*(D[f[u], {u, 2}]/f[u])^2 == 
   -2*
Pi^2*(Subscript[T, 0]^2 + (Subscript[T, 1]^2 - Subscript[T, 0]^2)*
          Exp[(-(2*\[Phi])^(-1))*(u - Subscript[u, 0])])},f[u], u]
```

Comment: `Mathematica` is not a **magic box** that'll spit out a solution to any problem.Try `NDSolve` instead. `Maple` cannot do it, either. All computer algebra systems, including `Mathematica`, are **limited** in their capabilities.

Comment: It is possible that the equation does not have a closed form solution. Try giving values to the parameters and the use NDSolve